# Transforming multiple rows into columns w. single row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need some help figuring out how best to transform an an array into a row-vector. My array looks like this:

```
+-----+-------+----------+
| ID  | Grade | Quantity |
+-----+-------+----------+
| Ape | Water | Y        |
| Ape | Juice | Y        |
| Ape | Milk  | Y        |
+-----+-------+----------+
```

Each ID can have up to 4 rows distinguished only by grade (Water, Juice, Beer, Milk); the list of possible values is static.

My desired output is this:

```
+-----+----------+-------+-------+------+------+
| ID  | Quantity | Water | Juice | Beer | Milk |
+-----+----------+-------+-------+------+------+
| Ape | Y        |     1 |     1 |    0 |    1 |
+-----+----------+-------+-------+------+------+
```

My own efforts have carried me as far as the PIVOT-operator, which transforms Grade-values into columns, but it doesn't group the rows by ID, leaving me with an equal number of rows post-transformation.

```
SELECT ID, Quantity, Water, Juice, Beer, Milk
FROM
    (SELECT ID, Grade, Quantity FROM Feeding WHERE ID = 'Ape') src
    PIVOT(
    COUNT(Quantity) FOR [Grade] IN (ID, Quantity, Water, Juice, Beer, Milk) 
    )AS TransformData
```

Output:

```
+-----+----------+-------+-------+------+------+
| ID  | Quantity | Water | Juice | Beer | Milk |
+-----+----------+-------+-------+------+------+
| Ape | Y        |     1 |     0 |    0 |    0 |
| Ape | Y        |     0 |     1 |    0 |    0 |
| Ape | Y        |     0 |     0 |    0 |    1 |
+-----+----------+-------+-------+------+------+
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about;

```
;WITH Feeding(id,grade,quantity) as (
    select 'Ape','Water','Y' union all
    select 'Ape','Juice','Y' union all
    select 'Ape','Juice','Y' union all
    select 'Ape','Juice','Y' union all
    select 'Ape','Juice','Y' union all
    select 'Ape','Milk', 'N' 
)

SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ID, Grade, Quantity agg, Quantity FROM Feeding WHERE ID = 'Ape') src
    PIVOT ( COUNT(agg) FOR [Grade] IN (Water, Juice, Beer, Milk) ) AS TransformData
```

--

```
ID  Quantity    Water   Juice   Beer    Milk
Ape N           0       0       0       1
Ape Y           1       4       0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try following query:-

```
SELECT ID, Quantity, CASE WHEN Grade = 'WATER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS WATER,
                     CASE WHEN Grade = 'JUICE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS JUICE,
                     CASE WHEN Grade = 'BEER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BEER,
                     CASE WHEN Grade = 'MILK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MILK
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, quantity,
case when grade = 'Water' then 1 else 0 end as Water,
when grade = 'Juice' then 1 else 0 end as Juice,
when grade = 'Milk' then 1 else 0 end as Milk,
when grade = 'Beer' then 1 else 0 end as Beer
from feeding
```

As the value list is static, this is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id
    ,quantity
    ,CASE 
        WHEN grade = 'Water'
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS Water
    ,when grade = 'Juice' then 1 ELSE 0 END AS Juice
    ,when grade = 'Milk' then 1 ELSE 0 END AS Milk
    ,when grade = 'Beer' then 1 ELSE 0 END AS Beer
FROM feeding
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get single row result

```
SELECT Id,Quantity,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Grade='Water' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Water,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Grade='Juice ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Juice ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Grade='Beer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Beer,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Grade='Milk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Milk
FROM Feed F 
GROUP BY Id,Quantity
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ad4c7/10)